# If I have a join model that joins two tables, how do I fetch all of the needed records in one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have three tables recipes, ingredients, and recipe_ingredients (which joins the prior two)

In my recipe_controller I want to have my index method return all of needed data to show a recipe to the user.

The schema looks like (removed useless info):

```
"ingredients",
    t.string "name"
    t.string "food_group"
  end

"recipe_ingredients",
    t.bigint "recipe_id"
    t.bigint "ingredient_id"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.string "measurement_unit"
  end

"recipes",
    t.string "name"
    t.string "genre"
    t.bigint "user_id"
```

I've tried something like

```
  def index
    recipe = Recipe.last
    recipe_ingredients = RecipeIngredient.where(recipe_id: recipe.id)
    ingredient_ids = recipe_ingredients.pluck(:id)
    ingredients = Ingredient.where('id in (?)', ingredient_ids)
    render json: { 
                  recipe: recipe, 
                  recipe_ingredients: recipe_ingredients,
                  ingredients: ingredients }
  end
```

to at least get one record correct, but I'm unsure where to begin when trying to create a general index method without writing a nasty, inefficient loop.

Also, I'm new to rails sql, and it is amazing, but I'm sure I'm missing a lot of optimization here so if there's something I can do to improve the above please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create following association in your recipie model

```
has_many :recipe_ingredients
has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
```

And in you controller

```
def index
  @recipies = Recipie.includes(recipe_ingredients: :ingredients)
end
```

This will load all the recipies, recipe_ingredients and ingredients in single query. And in your view you can iterate on `@recipies`

```
@recipies.each do |recipie|
  recipe_ingredients = recipie.recipe_ingredients
  ingredients = recipie.ingredients
end
```

Update:

```
def index
  @recipies = Recipie.includes(recipe_ingredients: :ingredients)
  recipie_with_ingredients = @recipies.map do |recipie|
                               {
                                 recipie: recipie,
                                 recipe_ingredients: recipie.recipe_ingredients,
                                 ingredients: recipie.ingredients
                               }
                             end
render json: recipie_with_ingredients
end
```

Comment: This is close, but the final object is still just the recipe data.

Ideally I'd have something like

{ recipe_one: { recipe_one_data }, recipe_two: { recipe_two_data } }

recipe_*_data is the collection of joined table data

Comment: @JackCollins that should be pretty straightforward now, You have the parent `@recipies` you can get all data from it and create hash as per your need by iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the help. the .map method seems to be exactly what I want.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful, please approve the answer.

Comment: Hi @JackCollins, I think you approved the wrong answer. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. Try this code out. It will actually generate a N+1 query if you want to display the ingredient and for example the quantity.

Comment: I have used `.includes(:recipe_ingredients, :ingredients)` and not `.includes(recipe_ingredients: :ingredients)` beacuse @JackCollins wanted `recipe_ingredients` and `ingredients` separately.

Comment: We can replace it to `.includes(recipe_ingredients: :ingredients)` this and the N+1 query issue will be solved.

Comment: Well, he's new and obviously lost. Neither of the two actually makes and sense without the other - would you really want one array of objects with just the quantity  and ingredient_id and and another with just the name and not the quantity if you're trying to display a recipe?

Comment: Yeah correct @max

Comment: Thanks @VishalJain, corrected it. And I'll look at this new discussion. Thanks for the input max

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with your ingredients.

First of all you can get the recipe_ingredients like this

```
recipe_ingredients = recipe.recipe_ingredients
```

Other thing is you are not getting ids of ingredients but these are recipe_ingredients which is the bridge table.

```
ingredient_ids = recipe_ingredients.pluck(:ingredient_id)
```

Now your code should be like

```
def index
  recipe = Recipe.last
  recipe_ingredients = recipe.recipe_ingrediants
  ingredient_ids = recipe_ingredients.pluck(:ingredient_id)
  ingredients = Ingredient.where(id: ingredient_ids)
  render json: { 
              recipe: recipe, 
              recipe_ingredients: recipe_ingredients,
              ingredients: ingredients }
```

end

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - the method I posted is working, but I'm wondering how to convert it an index method that can return similarly shaped data but for all records - like a dozen "recipes" which are built up of the corresponding tables.

Comment: This is a very kludged answer full of typos to a simple problem that can be handled by just using `eager_load` or `include` to avoid a n+1 query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume you don't actually want that JSON structure. Simply because it doesn't actually make sense given the overall goal. If you want to render a recipe you want to actually have quantity, name and unit together so that you don't have cobble the needed information together on the consuming end from two seperate arrays.

Ideally you would want JSON that resembles this:

```
{
  "name": "Chocolate Chip Cookies",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "name": "Butter",
      "quantity": 100,
      "measurement_unit": "gr"
    },
    {
      "name": "Flour",
      "quantity": 300,
      "measurement_unit": "gr"
    }
  ]
}
```

Provided you have the following assocations:

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
end
```

```
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

You can load the records off all three tables in a single query with:

```
@recipe = Recipe.eager_load(recipe_ingredients: :ingredient).last
```

This generates the following monster query:

```
SELECT
  "recipes"."id" AS t0_r0,
  "recipes"."name" AS t0_r1,
  "recipes"."created_at" AS t0_r2,
  "recipes"."updated_at" AS t0_r3,
  "recipe_ingredients"."id" AS t1_r0,
  "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" AS t1_r1,
  "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id" AS t1_r2,
  "recipe_ingredients"."quantity" AS t1_r3,
  "recipe_ingredients"."measurement_unit" AS t1_r4,
  "recipe_ingredients"."created_at" AS t1_r5,
  "recipe_ingredients"."updated_at" AS t1_r6,
  "ingredients"."id" AS t2_r0,
  "ingredients"."name" AS t2_r1,
  "ingredients"."created_at" AS t2_r2,
  "ingredients"."updated_at" AS t2_r3 
FROM
  "recipes" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "recipe_ingredients" 
    ON "recipe_ingredients"."recipe_id" = "recipes"."id" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "ingredients" 
    ON "ingredients"."id" = "recipe_ingredients"."ingredient_id"  
LIMIT 1
```

Note wierd the column aliases - thats how ActiveRecord knows what model to stuff each column in the result set into.

This will let you iterate through the associations without N+1 queries - like in this HTML example:

```
<article class="recipe">
  <h1><%= @recipe.name %></h1>
  <ul class="ingredients">
  <%= @recipe.recipe_ingredients.each do |ri| %>
    <li>
      <%= ri.quantity %><%= ri.measurement_unit %> <%= ri.ingredient.name %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Setting up an indirect assocation as in the other answers is generally a good idea but doing `.eager_load(:ingredients)` won't actually prevent a n+1 query when what you actually want to do is iterate across the `recipe_ingredients` assocation and the nested ingredient.

While you could render this as JSON with:

```
render json: @recipe, 
       include: { recipe_ingredients: :ingredient }
```

Its usually a better idea to move any kind of heavy lifting into a seperate serialization layer such as ActiveModel::Serializers or one of the many JSONAPI gems.

Comment: There is also the the whole question of why you're displaying a single record in the index action I'll leave that for later...

Comment: I think he has just added that for example but the goal is he want an index action with all recipes and ingredients.